# Google Data Studio Connector getData missing field

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio, hubspot

I am trying to create a data connector for HubSpot and have been banging my head against the wall trying to figure this out. As far as I can tell, I'm doing everything correctly but the request object in the `getData` call is missing one of my fields I've specified in my schema.

When I check the logs, `getSchema` is returning both fields but for some reason, I only appear to be getting one. I've included the code and logs below:

```
function getData(request) {
  console.log("ORIGINAL FIELDS FOR GETDATA(): " + JSON.stringify(request.fields));

  switch (request.configParams.apiEndPoint) {
    case "sources":
      var url = API_URL + "/analytics/v2/reports/totals/summarize/daily?start=" + startYYYYMMDD + "&end=" + endYYYYMMDD;   
      break;
    case "stages":
      console.info("Fetching for Stages API");
      var url = API_URL + "/deals/v1/pipelines/default";
      getPipelineData(request, url);
      break;
  }
}

function getPipelineData(request, endPoint) {
  var header_row = [];

  console.log("FIELDS: " + JSON.stringify(request));

  request.fields.forEach(function(field) {
    for (var i = 0; i < mySchema.length; i++) {
      console.log("for loop i: " + i);
      console.log("mySchema[i]: " + JSON.stringify(mySchema[i]));

      if (mySchema[i].name === field.name) {
        console.log("Matched " + mySchema[i].name + " to " + field.name);

        header_row.push(mySchema[i]);
      } else {
        console.error("Did not match " + mySchema[i].name + " to " + field.name);
      }
    }
  });
```

You can see in the log on about row 5 that `getSchema` is returning 2 fields, "label" and "stageId." Yet, the next line down in the log is showing the object being used by `getData` only has one field, "label."

I have NOT, for the life of me, been able to figure out where I'm going wrong here and could really use some help!

Here's a link to the log output: https://www.screencast.com/t/rpD7oz5ZuDdv

Comment: Based on those log timestamps, 3 minutes went by between those 2 lines. Your code here doesn't show how you invoke these functions with the given schema, or the given request. Note that globals in Apps Script are not persistent - they are reinitialized every time a project instance spools up - so you can't assign to them from a function and then assume that will be the value when you next read from them.

Answer (score 1):

getSchema() is called during the data source initialization/config. It is called for all fields and is done usually once when you are creating the data source.

getData() is called whenever you create/view chart elements on a dashboard and is called for only the specific fields in that chart element. This list of fields will be passed in request.fields.

This [workflow diagram](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/community-connectors/#3) might be of help.

From your log, line 3 and 4 happened when you were creating the data source. Line 5 happened when you added a chart element to your dashboard (and that chart element had only the `label` field).

Comment: Re: Promotion guidelines, it's recommended you disclose your affiliation to linked content. See [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers)

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. Could you please help me understand why you think the link / content might be considered "Promotion"?

Comment: Maybe promotion is a bit of a stretch, I just saw that the linked content contained a video you presented. Thought it might be worthwhile making note of that, as it could arguably reduce objectivity.

Comment: Thanks. I understand and agree with the rationale behind this. However, I feel in this specific case, disclosing the affiliation might not be required since:
1. The question was asked about the product itself and wasn't a general query. 2. The content I linked to and the video are both authoritative reference sources.  3. My affiliation with the product is directly mentioned in my profile page.

Comment: I fully agree with 1. and 2. , however I disagree with 3. being sufficient disclosure. Not here to attack/argue with you though, just thought it might be a worthwhile addition. Apologies if it came across as such.

Comment: No need to apologize. I think it was a useful and constructive feedback and I'm trying to figure out how to incorporate it in future posts. e.g. In this post, saying "Disclosure: link to self content" doesn't make sense since it's technically my employer's content. On the other hand, disclosing only my affiliation with the product doesn't convey that I developed the linked content. Have to find the right balance. Thanks again for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to your schema fields a group attribute.
While iterating through your fields in your getData function and before calling the API you can simply filter by the group when you are checking the type of the field in order to make the correct call. I drafted the functions to the api call. but the general idea is this.

```
 function getData(request) {
     var fieldsSchema = this.getFields()
     var requestedFields = request.fields.map(function (field) {
         for (var i = 0; i < fieldsSchema.length; i++) {
             if (fieldsSchema[i].name == field.name) {
                 return fieldsSchema[i];
             }
         }
     });

     var datatype = requestedFields.reduce(function (type, field) {
         if (!type) {
             return field['group'];
         }
         if (type !== field['group']) {
             console.log('You can only choose fields in the same group.')
         }
         return type;
     }, undefined);

     config.datatype = datatype;
     switch (config.datatype) {
         case 'sources':
             return this.getSourcesFromApi(request, config, requestedFields);
         case 'stage':
             return this.getStagesFromApi(request, config, requestedFields);
         default:
             console.log('Fields in the group not supported')
     }
 }


 function getSchema(){
    return {schema: this.getFields()};
 }

 // get fields could be something like this
 function getFields() {
     return [{
             "name": "date",
             "label": "Date",
             "description": "The date that this was created",
             "dataType": "STRING",
             "group": "stages"
         },
         {
             "name": "name",
             "label": "name",
             "dataType": "STRING",
             "group": "stages"
         }
     ]

 }
```

Comment: Make sure getSourcesFromApi and getStagesFromApi return the values you want.